# How to prove cancellation property of integer multiplication?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, integers

**How to prove that**
Multiplication has a cancellation property if $\langle 0, 0 \rangle$ is not a member of the factor to be canceled.

Comment: What is $\langle 0,0\rangle$, and what does it mean for it to be "a member of the factor"? Multiplication of *what*? You have both "number theory" (suggesting either natural numbers, integers, or perhaps rationals), and "real-analysis" (suggesting real numbers) in your question. A proof of the cancellation property depends on what you are taking for granted.

Comment: Please see: http://books.google.com/books?id=3-nrPB7BQKMC&lpg=PA135&ots=0l2CJNQ_F8&dq=Multiplication%20has%20a%20cancellation%20property%20if%20%E2%9F%A80%2C0%E2%9F%A9%20is%20not%20a%20member%20of%20the%20factor%20to%20be%20canceled.&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q=Multiplication%20has%20a%20cancellation%20property%20if%20%E2%9F%A80,0%E2%9F%A9%20is%20not%20a%20member%20of%20the%20factor%20to%20be%20canceled.&f=false

Comment: @Arturo: Please see my link. I think the sentence has been taken from there.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: Thanks. In short, we have the natural numbers, define the integers as the equivalence classes of pairs $(m,n)$ with $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, under equivalence relation $(m,n)\sim(r,s)$ if and only if $m+s=n+r$; and are trying to prove the cancellation property of multiplication in the integers. The book uses $\langle m,n\rangle$ for the ordered pair $(m,n)$.

Comment: @chandrasekhar I mean to say, that  if $ a=b \ne 0$, then $b(a-b)=(a+b)(a-b)$ doesn't mean that $b=a+b$. And Yes! It's an exercise in the book SET THEORY AND LOGIC by RR STOLL.

Comment: @arturo $\langle 0, 0\rangle$ is an ordered pair of zeros.

Comment: In the future, it's a good idea to mention what book you're looking at when you're trying to solve an exercise.

Comment: Also, what's so fundamental about this lemma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You start with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, which include $0$. The book linked to by Chandrasekhar assumes the usual properties of addition, multiplication, and order of natural numbers as part of the axiomatic set-up; these properties include cancellation for nonzero natural numbers.

Then we define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ by
$$(a,b)\sim (c,d) \Longleftrightarrow a+d = b+c.$$
It is not hard to establish that this is indeed an equivalence relation. We define the set $\mathbb{Z}$ to be the set $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ of equivalence classes modulo $\sim$. Let $[a,b]$ denote the equivalence class of $(a,b)$ under $\sim$.

We define addition of integers by
$$[a,b]+[c,d] = [a+c,b+d].$$
This is well-defined, and has the usual properties of addition.

Then we define multiplication of integers by:
$$[a,b]\times [c,d] = [ac+bd, ad+bc].$$

Since your question is about multiplication, I'll start actually proving things here.

**Theorem.** Multiplication is well defined. That is, if $(a,b)\sim (x,y)$ and $(c,d)\sim (v,w)$, then $(ac+bd,ad+bc) \sim (xv+yw, xw+yv)$.

*Proof.* First, I prove that $(ac+bd, ad+bc) \sim (xc+yd, xd+cy)$; indeed, we know that $a+y = b+x$. Multiplying by $c$, we have $ac+yc = bc+xc$. Multiplying by $d$, we get $ad+yd=bd+xd$. So $(ac+yc)+(bd+xd) = (bc+xc)+(ad+yd)$, which proves that $(ac+bd,ad+bc)\sim (xc+yd,xd+cy)$.

Next, I prove that $(xc+yd, xd+cy)\sim (xv+yw, xw+yv)$. We know $c+w=d+v$; multiplying by $x$ and by $y$, we get $xc + xw = xd+xv$ and $yc+yw = yd+yv$. Therefore,
$(xc+xw)+(yd+yv) = (xd+xv) + (yc+yw)$, which is what we want. By transitivity, we get the result. $\Box$

Therefore, multiplication of integers is well defined.

**Theorem.** Multiplication is commutative, associative, and distributes over sums.

*Proof.* Simply a matter of computing. $\Box$

**Theorem.** If $[a,b][x,y] = [a,b][r,s]$ and $a\neq b$, then $[x,y]=[r,s]$.

*Proof.* $[a,b][x,y] = [ax+by, ay+bx]$; $[a,b][r,s] = [ar+bs,as+br]$. Equality means that
$$ax+by+as+br = ay+bx+ar+bs.$$
We want to show that $x+s = y+r$. These are all natural numbers, so the usual properties hold.

Note that $ax+by+as+br = a(x+s) + b(y+r)$ and $ay+bx+ar+bs = a(y+r) + b(x+s)$.

If $a\lt b$, then we can write $b=a+h$ with $h\gt 0$. Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
a(x+s) + b(y+r) &= a(y+r) + b(x+s)\\
a(x+s) + a(y+r) + h(y+r) &= a(y+r) + a(x+s) + h(x+s)\\
h(y+r) &= h(x+s).
\end{align*}$$
Since $h\neq 0$, then $y+r=x+s$, as desired. If $a\gt b$, then we can write $a=b+h$ with $h\gt 0$, and a similar computation again shows that $x+s=y+r$, as desired. $\Box$

Now, note that $(0,0)\in[a,b]$ if and only if $(0,0)\sim (a,b)$, if and only if $a=b$. Therefore, in the integers (i.e., in $(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})/\sim$) we have that $[a,b][x,y] = [a,b][r,s]$ if and only if the ordered pair $(0,0)$ is not one of the elements of the equivalence class $[a,b]$.